# OpenLayers 3: per-layer translation for tiled image layers

Tags: openlayers-3

Sometimes it's useful to apply translation (that is, pixel offset) to a layer (and not other layers).

For example, two line-based layers can be visually compared by translating (that is, offsetting) a layer.

For vector layers, it can be done by translating vector features. But for the tiled image layers, (for example, road traffic information tiles generated by GeoServer) how can it be done?

Comment: So how does this end up? Is it missing anything?

Comment: @JonatasWalker Please read tsauerwein's answer for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a nice example for `precompose` and `postcompose` [render event](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.render.Event.html) handlers.

`precompose` is triggered before a layer is rendered, and `postcompose` afterwards. Inside the event handlers you have direct access to the canvas context, so you can use [CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) to offset the rendering for a layer.

```
roads2.on('precompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(10, 10);
});

roads2.on('postcompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.restore();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1abjrkm/3/

Note: This example does not take into account rotated maps!

**Update**: As @zeodtr points out in his comment, there is a problem at the tile borders with this approach. The following screenshot created by him illustrates the problem:

[image]

Comment: This does not work for tiled layers since the layer renders only the visible extent of the untranslated map. Please check your jsfiddle on the tile boundary.

Comment: I've edited your answer to show the problem. (it will be visible when the peer review is done.)