# In OpenLayers, is there a way to render Mapbox vector tiles in a translated layer?

Tags: openlayers

The recommended approach for translating a vector tile layer seems to be to translate the canvas context on precompose (see [OpenLayers 3: per-layer translation for tiled image layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511975/openlayers-3-per-layer-translation-for-tiled-image-layers)). As noted, only those tiles that fall within the map’s pre-translation visible extent are rendered.

How can I achieve the effect of translation without losing those boundary tiles?

I also tried using a custom tile grid with an origin (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9514) but this appears to be a misuse of the ‘origin’ parameter so tiles were only partially drawn. I am guessing that custom origins are required to fall on a tile boundary; mine do not.

Update: Mike’s solution is correct.   As I recall, I had tried Mike’s approach before submitting this question and, although the layer was translated, there was a problem with portions of tiles disappearing (or being drawn in the wrong location).    But experimenting with Mike’s example, I noticed that setting useInterimTilesOnError to false in my application fixed both the disappearing and misdrawn tile issue.    Perhaps there is some problem with the tiles I am using, but it is interesting that when the layer is not offset, tiles are rendered properly regardless of how useInterimTilesOnError is set.

Comment: One example is translating by pixels on the canvas (same number of pixels regardless of resolution), in the other you attempt to move the origin (same distance  on the ground regardless of resolution).  Which effect did you want?

Comment: @Mike The latter. But as I can readily convert between pixels and coordinates, the first example would work for me so long as the required tiles were not missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be sufficient to offset the extent of the tilegrid (the origin will default to the top left of the extent).

```js
var proj3857 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 23
  })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 50]),
      maxZoom: 23,
      zoom: 5,
      projection: proj3857
  })
});

var dx = -200000;
var dy = -100000;

var extent = proj3857.getExtent();
offsetExtent = [extent[0] + dx, extent[1] + dy, extent[2] + dx, extent[3] + dy];

var layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: offsetExtent, maxZoom: 18 })
  }),
  //useInterimTilesOnError: false,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 1,
      color: 'white'
    })
  })
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Console log from the OpenLayers example near Japan
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your example exhibits the same problem. Zoom in off the coast of Japan and, at some point, tiles (or portions thereof) disappear.

Comment: That's because there are no tiles available at some resolutions and locations. You can see the errors on the console log with the same tiles in this unaltered example openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-info.html Not turning off `useInterimTilesOnError` will help by keeping the previous zoom level visible (but can make the map look cluttered).

Comment: The area I was examining has no tile errors in either your version or the unaltered version in the area of center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([140.167898, 35.094744]) and zoom: 11. But a feature appears if you zoom out from there. Not sure what is going on there - maybe the polygon just doesn't exist at that higher zoom level? But appears unrelated to your proposal.

Comment: The console is full of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`because no tiles at zoom 11 in that area.

Comment: You will also see CORS errors because the server doesn't put a cross origin header on its error responses.

Comment: Make your browser window smaller. Those console errors you see are for tiles outside the area I was talking about out. Regardless, that Japan issue was a red herring and unrelated to your proposal since it happens in the unaltered version also.

Comment: There are tiles which don't load at various zoom levels all round the world.  It's probably best to test with a source which has full coverage, but that one was convenient as it has no access restrictions. A good alternative is `url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key=' + key,`  but you will need an API key from MapTiler, and set the tilegrid maxZoom to 14.